# asp.net core application connection after IIS binding update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

We have an asp.net Core application (that is running under .net Framework 4.8) which is deployed withing IIS on a Windows Server 2016 box.  This application uses asp.net Core identity framework for roles based access.

Everything works great but when we update the "Site Bindings" (by way of an example config change) within IIS all the connected users get logged out upin the next page request, perhaps the cookie/sessions being reset?!

Whilst this *might* be the behaviour you expect this was not the behavious we had on a previous "identical" installation which was lost (all data was backed up etc etc but the server host died and we lost the exact settings).

I remember reading a while back (but can't find it now) that the session should actually persist as this allows for load-balancing (which we don't need).

Nothing has changed in the code base for this to now not work so this suggests it's an IIS setting.

Does anyone have a magic change we can make for the connections to persists and our users not to be sent back to the logon page on the asp.net core app?

Thanks.

Jim.

*** update ***

Changing the "Identity" property of the Appl pool entry to System Account seems to allow me to change bindings without the (app pool?) reset.

Somewhat annoyingly, this appears to be the only setting that doesnt reset the user sesions when changing the binding.  The obv downside of using this are the security considerations which rule it out!

Anyone with a plan c?

Comment: What changes are you making to the bindings?

Comment: Sorry, been snowed.  

Basically any change (ie add new bindings or remove them) recycles the application pool subsequently causing logged in users to be logged out.  

What seems odd to me is that by using the "System Account" in the Identity prevents this from happening, but we can't use that account for security reasons.

Comment: I don't know if you are using data protection but if not you can use to keep alive the sessions